# How to reload when orientation changes. (Bxslider)

Tags: jquery, orientation, bxslider

I'm working with Bxslider and show 1 slide on portrait, and show 2 slides on landscape.

The problem is I need to reload when orientation changes(portrait/landscape).

Anyone know how make it ?

```
if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
    // Special  Slider   
        $('.wrap_mSpecial_list .bxslider').bxSlider({  
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 1, 
            auto:true,
            infiniteLoop: true,
            controls:false 
        }); 
    });
}

if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // Special  Slider   
        $('.wrap_mSpecial_list .bxslider').bxSlider({ 
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 2, 
            slideWidth: 5000,  
            auto:true,
            controls:false,
            infiniteLoop: true 
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery Mobile you could use this binder to listen for an orientation change:

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
   alert("The orientation has changed!");
   if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
       //landscape slider
   }
});
```

with pure js you could use this:

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
   console.log(event.alpha + ' : ' + event.beta + ' : ' + event.gamma);
});
```

Check out more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent)